# unable to create constraint in mysql table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I've got following tables:

```
node_sharing | CREATE TABLE `node_sharing` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `node_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`node_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_id_idx` (`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_node_id_idx` (`node_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and

```
users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `has_ard_access` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I would like to create following foreign key with a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `node_sharing`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )
  REFERENCES `users` (`id` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

and MySQL returns the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'MY_TABLE_NAME.#sql-4d0_218' (errno: 121)
```

What is wrong here?

PS `node_sharing` has been truncated, so there are no existing records that could disable putting the constraint on.

Comment: Hi,I tried to execute your 3 statements and it's OK. Which version of MySql have you got?

Comment: @JoeTaras it's `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a duplicate key error. Did you have a table with same name before? If so, check InnoDB internal data dictionary. If not, check if you have another constraint with same name. Constraint names should be unique.

Comment: you're right. I had the same constraint name in a different table. Thank you!

Comment: @JakeBuller yes, I know that. SO disables accepting the answer during first few minutes.